# Difference between Exponent operator ^ and Math.pow()

Tags: javascript, exponent

What is the difference between:

```
100 ^ 49; // = 85
```

and

```
Math.pow(100, 49); // = 1e+98
```

JavaScript returns different results and I don't know why.

Comment: The exponential operator is `**`, `100**49`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`^` isn't the exponentiation operator in JavaScript, `**` is (and only recently). `^` is a bitwise XOR. More on JavaScript operators [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

If you compare `100**49` to `Math.pow(100,49)`, according to the specification, there should be no difference; from [`Math.pow`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-math.pow):

> 1. Return the result of Applying the ** operator with *base* and *exponent* as specified in 12.6.4.

That may or may not be true of implementations at present, though, because again the exponentiation operator is quite new. For instance, as I write this, Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine returns **very slightly different** results for `100**49` and `Math.pow(100,49)`: *(Edit: As of 26/08/2020, they have the same result.)*

```js
console.log(100**49);
console.log(Math.pow(100,49));
```

Presumably disparities will be resolved as the implementations mature. The discrepancy appears to be covered by [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5848). It appears to be that `100*49` is evaluated at compile-time (since both values are constants), whereas of course `Math.pow` is evaluated at runtime, and apparently the algorithms aren't identical.

If you use a variable, `**` and `Math.pow` agree:

```js
let a = 100;
console.log(a**49);
console.log(Math.pow(a,49));
console.log(a**49 === Math.pow(a, 49));
```

On Firefox and Edge, the values are identical (even with constants).